# Can't redirect to another action method after form submission

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asynchronous

I want to redirect to an action that says Order is successful, but when the form is submitted, it redirects to the same action `/Checkout` with error: `This page isn't working`. This is understandble since the query strings are not present, but this doesn't matter to me. I want
it to redirect to `/OrderComplete` instead. The debugger confirmed ModelState is valid and RedirectToAction is hit every time.

These are the get and post action methods.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Checkout(string vendorId, int skillId)
{
    var skill = await _skillRepository.GetSkillById(skillId);
    OrderViewModel OrderView = new OrderViewModel
    {
        ApplicationUserId = vendorId,
        ServiceType = skill.SkillType
    };
    return View(OrderView);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Checkout(OrderViewModel orderViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _orderRepository.CreateOrder(orderViewModel);
        return RedirectToAction("OrderComplete");
    }
    return View(orderViewModel);
}
```

This is the form action in view.

```
<form asp-action="Checkout" method="post">
```

Note: `ApplicationUserId` and `ServiceType` are hidden fields that
are filled before posting the form.

**Update**

After commenting out this line `_orderRepository.CreateOrder(orderViewModel);`, it redirected successfully. So, the problem seems to be coming from this method `CreateOrder`.

```
public class OrderRepository : IOrderRepository
{
    private readonly QuickServiceDbContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    public OrderRepository(QuickServiceDbContext context, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
    public void CreateOrder(OrderViewModel orderViewModel)
    {
        Order order = _mapper.Map<Order>(orderViewModel);
        _context.Orders.Add(order);
        //_context.Users
        _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `OrderComplete` present in the same controller?

Comment: @Rahatur Yes, OrderComplete is present.

Comment: So the `_orderRepository.CreateOrder(orderViewModel);` line is executing the code is going to the `OrderComplete` action? In that case what is the error on the screen and what is the code in that action?

Comment: @Rahatur No, `CreateOrder` is just for mapping and saving the data in the database. This is the code - Line 1 `Order order = _mapper.Map<Order>(orderViewModel);` Line 2 `_context.Orders.Add(order);` Line 3 `_context.SaveChangesAsync();`

Comment: Why are you doing this `return await Task.FromResult(View(orderViewModel));` instead of just `return View(orderViewModel);`? Also, please show the `OrderComplete` action method.

Comment: @IanKemp Since the action method is asynchronous and I initially planned to make the `CreateOrder` method asynchronous, I had to make something in the code asynchronous to prevent errors but it makes no difference when I remove it. The problem is not with the `OrderComplete` action method as I have tried to redirect to other action methods as well and got the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `_context.SaveChangesAsync()` to:

```
_context.SaveChanges();
```

fixed the issue. I don't understand why this is yet, but I should never have spent so much time on an issue so trivial. Any insight into why `SaveChangesAsync()` was preventing a redirection would be appreciated.